# How to prevent to my Xamarin app not be crashed at run time or ANR Pop ups

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Users are complaining about app crash and sometime App not responding pop ups coming to my users.

I have checked the Vitals through the google play console and found the below stack trace is coming from all set of phone.

Could any help me resolve this issue please. **App build by using Xamarin.Forms**

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable

crc64f1353ff377cb4a5c.LocationTrackingService.n_onStartCommand  



android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at LastMile.Droid.ForgroundServices.LocationTrackingService.OnStartCommand (Android.Content.Intent intent, Android.App.StartCommandFlags flags, System.Int32 startId) [0x00000] in <50ef6ae12d4d4ffbac5dfb2ebcdb9470>:0
at Android.App.Service.n_OnStartCommand_Landroid_content_Intent_II (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_intent, System.Int32 native_flags, System.Int32 startId) [0x0000f] in <fc04d8327ea64fbbbf46b8a5be6232c0>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int)
  at crc64f1353ff377cb4a5c.LocationTrackingService.n_onStartCommand (Native Method)
  at crc64f1353ff377cb4a5c.LocationTrackingService.onStartCommand (LocationTrackingService.java:40)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:4758)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:301)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2188)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8577)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Hi Kettan, some of the tasks are running in UI thread. Make sure long running tasks are handled in background.

Comment: Thanks for Instant respond Babin. If this is the issue I will check and work upon it. Meanwhile I am furthermore happy to have other workaround as well if any .

Comment: Exception handling must help

Comment: Thanks Junaid but, let me check and update